# Operations with properties file causing issues in Java

Tags: java, properties-file

I want to append new entry to already exiting properties file, I used below code and what I received in properties file is like

```
 #Path to test directory
 #Tue Dec 15 11:36:24 IST 2015
 TestPath=C\:/temp/TestDir
```

1. I got to know from oracle docs that this`(C\:/temp.....)` is valid case.Is there any way to get rid of this and the time-date comment also as this is not looking good ?
2. above operation needs to be done frequently, and its adding same newer entry every time run the code, I can see multiple entries for this in properties file, I want to have only one.

I read that file should not be opened in append mode to have correct output after remove operation, but if not then how to append new entry to properties file.

```
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("TestPath", "C:/temp/TestDir");
        File file = new File("D:\\test.properties");
        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(file,true);
        properties.store(fileOut, "Path to test directory");
        System.out.println(properties.getProperty("TestPath"));  // prints correct one.

        properties.remove("TestPath");
        properties.store(fileOut,null);
        fileOut.close();
```

Comment: "Is there any way to get rid of this" of what? Either you want to replace the content or append to it but you cannot do both with one output stream. I would suggest to read the properties (`Properties.load`), make your changes to the `Properties` object, then store (no append!).

Answer (score 0):

If you need this you must Override the methode store0 of java.util.Properties file. By default, it adds the timestamp as a comment.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, this is one part of my first question.

Comment: Please upvote if yu find that useful. Glad it helped :)